# Python3 - parse_qs doesn't separate arguments as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib

I'm using the `urllib`-library in Python3. The code:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
parse_qs('https://www.example.com/?api-url=%2Fp%2Ftest-test-test-000761di%3Fajax%3Dtrue&api-params=%3Ft%3Dst-fs%26tc%3Dtrue')
```

returns the dictionary:

```
{
  'https://www.example.com/?api-url': ['/p/test-test-test-000761di?ajax=true'], 
  'api-params': ['?t=st-fs&tc=true']
}
```

Can someone explain to me how the dictionary is constructed?

Why is `...?api-url` and `&api-params`a key, but `?ajax`, `?t`, `&tc` isn't? Where can I read on the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_qs()` expects *just the query string*. You passed in a full URL.

If you pass in *only the query string*, you get:

```
>>> parse_qs('api-url=%2Fp%2Ftest-test-test-000761di%3Fajax%3Dtrue&api-params=%3Ft%3Dst-fs%26tc%3Dtrue')
{'api-url': ['/p/test-test-test-000761di?ajax=true'], 'api-params': ['?t=st-fs&tc=true']}
```

This is the correct result for the given query string; the `?`, `=` and `&` characters you see in the output are *escaped* in the input query string.

For example, the escaped value for `api-params` is `%3Ft%3Dst-fs%26tc%3Dtrue`; the correct interpretation is the unquoted value for that string, which is `'?t=st-fs&tc=true'`.

You could then parse those values *again*, to remove the second layer of query-string syntax, but you must parse out the query strings:

```
>>> parsed['api-url'][0].partition('?')[-1]
'ajax=true'
>>> parse_qs(parsed['api-url'][0].partition('?')[-1])
{'ajax': ['true']}
>>> parsed['api-params'][0].partition('?')[-1]
't=st-fs&tc=true'
>>> parse_qs(parsed['api-params'][0].partition('?')[-1])
{'t': ['st-fs'], 'tc': ['true']}
```

I used [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split the strings on the first `?` character, and to get everything after that first character to be parsed as the query string.

Comment: Thank you! Can you expand a little on your second paragraph (why this is the expected result)?

Comment: @user9115052: the values may themselves be URLs, but they were properly quoted to protect them from accidentally being interpreted as query parameters.

Comment: @user9115052: so each value for each of the two keys are *separate, partial URLs with query strings*, those query strings can only be part of another query string if first escaped.

Comment: Oh, so my url contains two query-parameters, which themselves may contain query parameters?

Comment: I'm mainly interested in getting out the `/p/test-test-test-000761di` out of my url. Can you point me in the right direction, how to extract these information properly?

Comment: @user9115052: yes, almost. They are partial URLs (a URL path with query string for `api-url`, and just the query string with the `?` delimiter still attached for the `api-params` parameter).

Comment: @user9115052: I don't know the range of values this can contain. If it is always a URL path with optional query string, just use `str.partition()` as I used in my example: `parsed['api-url'][0].partition('?')[0]`.